# ¿Crear un counter que permita contar el numero de reservaciones hechas?

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo esta duda desde hace unos dias, y como no consegui información al respecto, decidi hacer la pregunta aqui.

Yo tengo un formulario que me permite hacer reservaciones de computadores, me gustaria saber si se puede hacer un codigo que permita contar el numero de computadores usados y mandar un mensaje si se llenó (Es decir, el limite es 15 computadores al dia, si una persona reserva 5 y la otra 10, la persona que sigue no puede reservar por el resto del dia porque esta lleno)

¿Es posible hacer eso?

Esto es lo que tengo.

```
<?php include('nuevocdt.php'); ?>
<div id="formularionuevaclase"> 
<center><h2>Nueva clase</h2></center>
<center><h3>Todos los campos son requeridos</h3></center>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://browser-update.org/es/update-browser.html" target="_blank">Si no puede ver los campos de fecha y hora, haga click para ver si necesita actualizar su navegador</a></div>
```

```
 <form method="POST" action ="cdt.php"/> <!-- El formulario en si -->
 <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
 <center><h3>Coloque todos los datos pedidos</h3></center>
 <br></br>
 <center><label for="nom"><b>Nombre</b></label></center>
 <center>
 <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['nombre']); ?>" placeholder="Escriba el nombre del profesor" name="nombre" id ="nombre"<?php echo $nombre; ?> ></input>
 </center>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>

 <center><label for="mat"><b>Materia que da</b></label></center>

<center>
 <select name="materia" id="materia" <?php echo $materia; ?>> 
 <option value="INTRODUCCION A LA COMPUTACION">INTRODUCCION A LA COMPUTACION</option>   
<option value="PROGRAMACION I">PROGRAMACION I</option>        
<option value="PROGRAMACION II">PROGRAMACION II</option>   
<option value="PROGRAMACION III">PROGRAMACION III</option> 
<option value="PROGRAMACION IV">PROGRAMACION IV</option> 
<option value="PROGRAMACION V">PROGRAMACION V</option> 
<option value="PROGRAMACION VI">PROGRAMACION VI</option> 
<option value="PROGRAMACION VII">PROGRAMACION VII</option>  
<option value="INTERACCION HUMANO - COMPUTADOR">INTERACCION HUMANO - COMPUTADOR</option>   
<option value="TECNICAS DE PROGRAMACION">TECNICAS DE PROGRAMACION</option>     
<option value="SISTEMAS OPERATIVOS I">SISTEMAS OPERATIVOS I</option> 
<option value="SISTEMAS OPERATIVOS II">SISTEMAS OPERATIVOS II</option>
<option value="INGENIERIA DEL SOFTWARE">INGENIERIA DEL SOFTWARE</option>  
<option value="COMPUTACION I">COMPUTACION I</option>        
<option value="COMPUTACION II">COMPUTACION II</option>   
<option value="COMPUTACION III">COMPUTACION III</option> 
<option value="COMPUTACION IV">COMPUTACION IV</option> 
<option value="COMPUTACION V">COMPUTACION V</option> 
<option value="COMPUTACION VI">COMPUTACIONVI</option> 
<option value="COMPUTACION VII">COMPUTACION VII</option>  
<option value="COMPUTACION VIII">COMPUTACION VIII</option>  
<option value="COMPUTACION IX">COMPUTACION IX</option>  
<option value="COMPUTACION X">COMPUTACION X</option>  
<option value="TOPOGRAFIA">TOPOGRAFIA</option>  
<option value="ESTRUCTURAS I">ESTRUCTURAS I</option>  
<option value="ESTRUCTURAS II">ESTRUCTURAS II</option>
<option value="PUENTES">PUENTES</option>
<option value="DIBUJO">DIBUJO</option>
</select>   
</center>

<br></br>
<br></br>

<center><label for="fec"><b>Fecha</b></label></center>
 <center>
<input type="date" name="fecha" min= <?php echo date('Y-m-d');?> id ="fecha" required<?php echo $fecha; ?>"></input>
</center>

 <br></br>
 <br></br>

<center><label for="hor1"><b>Hora a la que empieza</b></label></center>
<center>
<input type="time" min="08:30" max="16:00" name="fechaemp" id ="fechaemp" required<?php echo $fechaemp; ?>"></input>
</center>

<br></br>
<br></br>

<center><label for="hor2"><b>Hora a la que termina</b></label></center>
<center>
<input type="time" min="09:30" max="17:00" name="fechater" id ="fechater" required<?php echo $fechater; ?>"></input>
</center>

<br></br>
<br></br>

<center><label for="num"><b>Número de computadores a usar (Maximo 15)</b></label></center>
<center>
<input type="number" placeholder="Escriba el numero de pcs a usar" min="1" max="15" name="numero" id ="numero"<?php echo $numero; ?> ></input>
</center>

<br></br>
<br></br>

<div style="text-align: center">
<input type="submit" aling="center" id="submit" name="submit" value="Crear clase"></input>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center" class="container" aling="center" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<button type="Reset" class="floated">Limpiar campos</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Lo que tengo en nuevocdt.php

```
<?php
// Iniciar variables
$nombre = "";
$materia = "";
$fecha = "";
$fechaemp = '';
$fechater = '';
$numero = '';
$errors = array(); 
$res="EXITO!"; //Si todo sale bien

$today_start = strtotime('today');
$today_end = strtotime('tomorrow');

// conectar a la base de datos
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

// registrar usuario

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Obtener todos los datos de la forma
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nombre']);
$materia = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['materia']);
$fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fecha']);
$fechater = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fechater']);
$fechaemp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fechaemp']);
$numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero']);
$salon = 'CDT';

// Muestra los errores si de alguna manera el usuario nego los required
if (empty($nombre)) { array_push($errors, "El nombre no esta"); }
if (empty($materia)) { array_push($errors, "La materia no esta"); }
if (empty($fecha)) { array_push($errors, "La fecha no esta"); }
if (empty($fechaemp)) { array_push($errors, "La hora de inicio no esta"); }
if (empty($fechater)) { array_push($errors, "La hora de terminacion no esta"); }
if (empty($numero)) { array_push($errors, "No se especificó el numero de computadores"); }

// Evitar que el usuario meta la hora de comienzo igual de la hora de terminacion
if($fechaemp === $fechater){
echo '';
echo 'Algo salio mal';
echo '';
  array_push($errors, "Las horas de entrada y salida son iguales, cambielas");
}

if($fechater < $fechaemp){
echo '';
echo 'Algo salio mal';
echo '';
  array_push($errors, "La hora a la que comienza la clase y la hora a la que termina la clase no tienen sentido, cambielas");
}

// Revisar si hay una clase en exactamente el mismo dia y la misma hora

$date_check_query = "SELECT * FROM reservatodo WHERE fecha='$fecha' AND salon='$salon' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $date_check_query);
$date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($date) { // Si ya existe la clase
 if ($date['fecha'] === $fecha AND $date['salon']===$salon) {
  echo ''; 
  echo 'Algo salio mal';
  echo '';
  array_push($errors, "Ya hay una clase en ese dia y en esa misma hora");
 }
 }

 // Si no hay errores, hace el insertar
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO reservatodo(nombre, materia, salon, fecha, fechaemp, fechater, numero, fechainscripcion) 
          VALUES('$nombre', '$materia', 'CDT', '$fecha', '$fechaemp', '$fechater', '$numero', now())";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
echo $res;
  }

  }
```

Edit, esta es mi tabla:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 15-05-2019 a las 16:01:48
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.35-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `prueba`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `reservatodo`
--

CREATE TABLE `reservatodo` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`materia` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`salon` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`fecha` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`fechaemp` time NOT NULL,
`fechater` time NOT NULL,
`numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fechavideo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`fechainscripcion` date NOT NULL,
`Conteo` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `reservatodo`
--

 INSERT INTO `reservatodo` (`id`, `nombre`, `materia`, `salon`, `fecha`, `fechaemp`, `fechater`, `numero`, `fechavideo`, `fechainscripcion`, `Conteo`) VALUES
 (21, 'gokdari', 'COLOR', 'diseno', '2019-02-12', '15:00:00', '15:30:00', 1, '00:00:00', '2019-02-05', 0),
 (34, 'gokdari', 'DISENO I', 'diseno', '2019-02-06', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', 2, '00:00:00', '2019-02-06', 0),
 (40, 'eee', 'INTRODUCCION A LA COMPUTACION', 'aula_virtual', '2019-02-14', '09:00:00', '12:00:00', 3, '00:00:00', '2019-02-06', 0),
 (41, 'gokdari', 'MATEMATICA DISCRETA I', 'biblioteca', '2019-02-20', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', 3, '00:00:00', '2019-02-20', 0),
 (42, 'bbb', 'INTERACCION HUMANO - COMPUTADOR', 'CDT', '2019-02-27', '11:00:00', '12:00:00', 4, '00:00:00', '2019-02-20', 0),
 (43, 'Juan Paiva', 'INTRODUCCION A LA COMPUTACION', 'CDT', '2019-04-11', '15:00:00', '17:00:00', 7, '00:00:00', '2019-04-11', 0),
 (44, 'aaa', 'COMPUTACION II', 'videobeam', '', '10:00:00', '12:00:00', 0, '2019-05-14', '2019-05-13', 0),
 (46, 'gokdari', 'INTRODUCCION A LA COMPUTACION', 'videobeam', '', '10:00:00', '12:00:00', 0, '2019-05-16', '2019-05-14', 0),
 (47, 'gokdari', 'INTRODUCCION A LA COMPUTACION', 'CDT', '2019-05-14', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', 2, '', '2019-05-14', 0);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

 --
 -- Indices de la tabla `reservatodo`
 --
 ALTER TABLE `reservatodo`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `reservatodo`
--
ALTER TABLE `reservatodo`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=48;
 COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

EDIT:

Intente hacer esto y no funciono, es la parte del if de conteo la que no funciona

```
<?php
// Iniciar variables
$nombre = "";
$materia = "";
$fecha = "";
$fechaemp = '';
$fechater = '';
$numero = '';
$errors = array(); 
$res="EXITO!"; //Si todo sale bien

$today_start = strtotime('today');
$today_end = strtotime('tomorrow');

// conectar a la base de datos
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

// registrar usuario

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Obtener todos los datos de la forma
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nombre']);
$materia = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['materia']);
$fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fecha']);
$fechater = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fechater']);
$fechaemp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fechaemp']);
$numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero']);
$salon = 'CDT';

// Muestra los errores si de alguna manera el usuario nego los required
if (empty($nombre)) { array_push($errors, "El nombre no esta"); }
if (empty($materia)) { array_push($errors, "La materia no esta"); }
if (empty($fecha)) { array_push($errors, "La fecha no esta"); }
if (empty($fechaemp)) { array_push($errors, "La hora de inicio no esta"); }
if (empty($fechater)) { array_push($errors, "La hora de terminacion no esta"); }
if (empty($numero)) { array_push($errors, "No se especificó el numero de computadores"); }

// Evitar que el usuario meta la hora de comienzo igual de la hora de terminacion
if($fechaemp === $fechater){
echo '';
echo 'Algo salio mal';
echo '';
  array_push($errors, "Las horas de entrada y salida son iguales, cambielas");
}

if($fechater < $fechaemp){
echo '';
echo 'Algo salio mal';
echo '';
  array_push($errors, "La hora a la que comienza la clase y la hora a la que termina la clase no tienen sentido, cambielas");
}

// Revisar si hay una clase en exactamente el mismo dia y la misma hora

$date_check_query = "SELECT * FROM reservatodo WHERE fecha='$fecha' AND salon='$salon' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $date_check_query);
$date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($date) { // Si ya existe la clase
 if ($date['fecha'] === $fecha AND $date['salon']===$salon) {
  echo ''; 
  echo 'Algo salio mal';
  echo '';
  array_push($errors, "Ya hay una clase en ese dia y en esa misma hora");
 }
 }

      $count_query = "SELECT SUM(Conteo) FROM reservatodo WHERE fecha='$fecha' AND salon='CDT'";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $count_query); 
 $conteo =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

if($conteo = 15){
 echo ''; 
 echo 'Algo salio mal';
 echo '';
 array_push($errors, "No hay computadores disponibles en esa fecha, intente otra fecha");
 }

 // Si no hay errores, hace el insertar
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO reservatodo(nombre, materia, salon, fecha, fechaemp, fechater, numero, fechainscripcion) 
          VALUES('$nombre', '$materia', 'CDT', '$fecha', '$fechaemp', '$fechater', '$numero', now())";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
echo $res;
  }

  }
```

Comment: que es el campo conteo? yo creo que querias un COUNT(conteo) (o cualquier otro campo). Sum suma el contenido del campo, count cuenta cuantas veces aparece...